# Como versionar um componente do Joomla com git

Tags: git, github, versionamento, joomla

Quando crio um novo componente ou modulo para Joomla, a maior parte do desenvolvimento é feita com o componente/modulo já instalado dentro da estrutura do CMS

```
- administrator
    - cache
    - components
        - com_component*
            - <arquivos do componente>
    - help
    - includes
    - language
    - logs
    - manifests
    - modules
    - templates
- bin
- cache
- cli
- components
    - com_component*
        - <arquivos do componente>
- images
- includes
- installation
- language
- layouts
- libraries
- media
- modules
- plugins
- templates
- tmp
```

Minha duvida está em como versionar os arquivos do projeto dentro da estrutura do Joomla.

Caso eu use `.gitignore` para ignorar TODOS os outros arquivos do Joomla, meu repositório ficaria assim:

```
- administrator
    - components
        - com_component*
            - <arquivos do componente>
- components
    - com_component*
        - <arquivos do componente>
```

Mas eu gostaria que ele possuísse a estrutura de um componente Joomla pronto para ser instalado, algo como:

```
- admin
    - <arquivos do componente>
- site
    - <arquivos do componente>
- manifest.xml
```

Comment: Da uma pesquisada em submodules

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Ferramentas-do-Git-Subm%C3%B3dulos

Answer (score 0):

Guilherme, realmente é necessário fazer o versionamento dentro da estrutura do Joomla?

No caso, a maioria dos desenvolvedores ( inclusive eu ), publica o código-fonte do pacote instalável nos repositórios SVN ou Git. Isso possibilita que o componente possa ser instalado em outro site caso necessário.

Desde configurado corretamente o arquivo *xml*, o pacote sempre vai poder ser instalado em outro site Joomla.

**Documentação da criação de componentes:** https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component